# No me sale el "Hola mundo" en Django con VisualStudio Code

Tags: python, vscode

Creo la funcion en el views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def saludo(request):

    return HttpResponse("Hola quillo")
```

importo la funcion y llamo a la funcion en el path del url

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Proyecto1.views import saludo

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('saludo/', saludo),
]
```

Levanto el server de python. Voy al navegador y pongo localhost:8000/saludo/
Y me da error 404 que no encuentra el path "saludo/"

Ayuda porfavor, no se que es lo que pasa que me de un error con un proyecto tan fácil

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aqui el error, nose que tengo mal en el codigo. Server levantado

Comment: El mensaje de error te muestra que sólo la ruta `admin/` está definida. Parece que el código que muestras no es el mismo que el que ejecutas. ¿Has guardado el fichero antes de lanzar de nuevo el servidor?

Comment: Exacto!! tengo definido el path saludo y llamando al metodo saludo de la views.

Comment: He probado si era error del servidor y esta ok. Pongo localhost:8000/admin y me sale el login del administrador.

Comment: La cosa es de que lo tengo bien definido como me mostro mi profesor y no va. El codigo esta igual. Puede ser que la version de Django o Python sea la del el mas atigua pero no entiendo donde esta el error. En el codigo, en mi editor de texto que me falte alguna configuracion o extension.. he hecho todo para que funcione.